Probability of a random ball being red
There's a bag and it contains 4 red balls, 3 green balls, and 2 blue balls.
Probability that a random ball is red = $P(R) = \frac{4}{9}$
Probability that a random ball is green = $P(G) = \frac{3}{9}$
Probability that a random ball is  blue = $P(B) = \frac{2}{9}$
Question:
What is the most likely color of a random ball from this bag?
Is the answer red, because $P(R) > P(G) > P(B)$?
I ask because we can see that the probability of the ball being either green or blue = $\frac{3}{9} + \frac{2}{9} = \frac{5}{9}$ and the answer to the question seems to be either green or blue.
We have 2 answers now:

The random ball is probably red.
The random ball is probably blue or green. This is equivalent to saying: the random ball is probably not red.

Which is the correct answer? 1 and 2 seem to be contradictories
Danke.
Edit

In Figure A, we have the probability distribution of individual colors and, clearly, red balls are more probable than either green or blue.
In Figure B, we have combined green and blue, but this time, non-red balls are more probable.
Which distribution answers the question "what is the likely color of a random ball drawn from this bag?"

$2$ doesn't make sense.  You are asked for the most probable color, not the most probable pair of colors.  And if you were asked for the most probable pair, then the answer would be "red or green".

But look at the equivalent statement: the random ball is probably not red. Either the ball is red or not red and it tallies.

So what?  The most common boy's name in the US is James (let's say).  Of course, if you select a boy uniformly at random, it's most likely that his name is not James.  No contradiction there.

If you want a more mathematical example, say you are tossing a pair of fair dice.  The most likely outcome is $7$, but it is more probable that that you will throw a non-$7$.

It looks like a contradiction to me. The ball is probably red because, in essence, there are more red balls than any other colored ball, but then there are more non-red balls too.

Asking for the most probable outcome of a single trial means looking at each possible outcome and selecting the one with the greatest probability.  There is no reason at all for that "most probable outcome" to have probability greater than $\frac 12$.

Will wait for other responses @lulu, thank you. Will be going over what you said too.

The difficulty is that your intuition has not caught up with your math.The solution is to actually find the right probability book for you, open it to page 1, and attack.  This is the only way that I know of, for a math student to develop their intuition.  In other words, there is no quick fix for undeveloped intuition.

@user2661923, Absolute probability: The ball is probably either green or blue. Relative probability: The ball is probably red than green or blue

To the Original Poster : Your last comment doesn't affect my opinion.  The fact that you posted the (quite reasonable) question, in and of itself, indicates that your intuition is undeveloped.

@user2661923, si and ok, my intuition is undeveloped. What is the answer though, to my question.

@lulu, a probability $> 0.5$ would settle the matter, yes. I wouldn't be confused

Please leave an answer, because extended discussions get moved to chat.

Perhaps a relatable analogy will help. Anyone?

The answer to your question is that once you develop your intuition, any notion of a paradox or contradiction will dissipate.  I repeat - there is no quick fix for undeveloped intuition.

@user2661923, last call for Paris. Please leave an answer.

@Hudjefa I (and I think most people) have been assuming that you were a learner confused about probability, but looking at your post history I guess that's not the case. It would have been helpful and more productive if you had said where you were coming from to start with.

You asked for a probability of observing a color--this implies an outcome that is a single identifiable color out of the set of all colors represented in the bag.
If I ask you, what are the elements of the set $\{1, 3, 7, 14\}$, you would say the elements are $1$, $3$, $7$ and $14$.  You would not call $\{1, 3\}$ or $\{1, 7, 14\}$ elements.  These are subsets of the given set.
We can define probabilities on outcomes and events.  But the wording of your question--"what is the most likely color of a random ball from this bag?"--does not insinuate that we should combine the outcomes of more than one color.  If you asked instead

What are the two most likely colors of a random ball from this bag?

this could be interpreted as asking among which two colors a randomly drawn ball is most likely to be, and this would be red and green.
There is no contradiction in the statements "the most likely color of a ball is red" and "the probability that a randomly drawn ball is not red is greater than the probability that it is red."  The same thing can be said of rolling a fair six-sided die:  the probability you roll a $1$ is $1/6$, and the probability you do not roll a $1$--i.e., you roll any other number--is $5/6$.  Your confusion stems from thinking that the event of getting a "non-red" ball is an elementary outcome on the same level as obtaining a specific color.  And it is not, for the same reason that a subset of a set is not necessarily an element of a set.

I confess I didn't quite get that, but you seem to be saying I'm conflating elements of a set with subsets of the set. Thank you for bringing in sets to the discussion.

The subsets are all possible combinations of the elements in a set. I'm drawing $1$ ball and want to know its most likely color. Not red, $P(\neg R) = 5/9$ and $P(R) = 4/9$ and so $P(\neg R) > P(R)$. Correct? We could say that I'm interested in the subset ${R_1, R_2, R_3, R_4 }$

Let us clearly define:

Event $A$ is more likely (more probable) than event $B$ when $P(A)> P(B)$.

If event $A$ is more likely than event $B$, then event $A$ is more likely to occur than event $B$.
In your example, event $R$ is more likely than each of events $G$ and $B$. However, event $G\cup B$ is more likely than $R$.

Defining the most likely event is useless, unless it is considered on a set of events that is smaller than the sigma-filed $\mathcal F$ defined on the sample space $\Omega$ ($\mathcal F$ is typically considered $2^\Omega$ when $\Omega$ is a countable set). Indeed, the most likely event in $\mathcal F$, if exists, is nothing but $\Omega$, whenever $1=P(\Omega)>P(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal F \setminus \{\Omega\}$. Note that some events may be equally likely to occur.
In your example, event $R$ is the most likely one among all simple events, but not all events. In general, the most likely event is $\Omega=R\cup G\cup B$. The most likely event in $\mathcal F \setminus \{\Omega\}$ is $R\cup G$.

Most of that went over my head. So then it's unlikely that a random ball is red. Despite the fact that there are more red balls than other-color balls? Doesn't that mean that if someone said "I have a bag and it contains red balls and at least 2 other-color balls and for any other color, there are more red balls than that color. What is the color of a random ball?", I should say "not red". I believe this is what we call counterintuitive

To avoid any confusion, we need to make our statements more precise. So I suggest saying that a random ball is more unlikely to be red, or a random ball is less likely to be red, or a random ball is more likely not to be red.

The setting for this kinda situation would be number of red balls = r, the number of green balls = g, the number of blue balls = b. r > b, r > g, but r < b + g

A random ball is more likely to be red than green and is more likely to be red than blue and is more likely to be red than blue. However a random ball is more likely to be non-red than red.

Exactly. We can also say a random ball is more likely to have color other than red, or a random ball is less likely to be red than green or blue.

nothing about that strikes you as odd? Red balls being more numerous than any other color balls, yet it's unlikely that a random ball is red.

Nothing odd as red balls are not more numerous than both green and blue balls, i.e., non-red balls (while they are more numerous than green balls and  more numerous than blue balls).

We can say an event is probable if it has a probability more than $\frac12$ of happening.'The ball is probably blue or green' doesn't imply that either 'the ball is probably blue' or 'the ball is probably green', because it is possible that $P(B)+P(G)>\frac12$ but neither $P(B)>\frac12$ or $P(G)>\frac12$.
When you have more than two possibilities, it is possible that neither of them are probable, as it might be that none of them have probability $>\frac12$, as is the case in your example. It can also happen with only two possibilities if they both have probability $\frac12$.
The issue is that red being 'most probable' out of red, green and blue, doesn't imply it is probable. It just means $P(R)$ is higher than $P(G)$ or $P(B)$.
And whether something is 'most probable' depends on what you compare it to. If you compare $R$ to the two separate events $B$ and $G$, we find $R$ is most probable, because $P(R)>P(B)$ and $P(R)>P(G)$, but if we compare it to the single event '$B$ or $G$' (denoted $B \cup G$) we find $P(R)<P(B \cup G)$ so $R$ is not most probable in that comparison.
Comparing $R$ to $B$ and $G$ put together is calculating a different thing to comparing $R$ to $B$ and $G$ separately, so it's not the same comparison. So $R$ can be 'most probable' in one comparison but not the other.

So, you agree it is unlikely that the random ball is red. Despite it being more numerous than any other colored ball. Doesn't this strike you as odd?

@Hudjefa It's unlikely if unlikely means it has less than $\frac12$ chance. It's not that unlikely though, so it wouldn't be surprising to pick a red ball. Likelihood is a spectrum. This doesn't seem odd to me. Imagine there are 90 people with 90 bags, and 40 pull out red balls, 30 pull out green balls, 20 pull out blue balls. That's what we're saying will happen, on average. What's paradoxical about that?

So nothing unusual or out-of-the-ordinary? That we have (relatively) more red balls and yet it's unlikely that a random ball is red.

@Hudjefa yes, because all 'unlikely' means is that it would happen in less than half of cases. That doesn't mean it won't happen. In the 90 people example does it strike you as odd that more people pulled red balls rather than blue or green but it was still less than half the people?

If it still seems odd, you could do an experiment yourself: get a random number generator to pick a number from 1 to 9, and count 1 to 4 as 'red', 5 to 7 as 'green' and 8 or 9 as 'blue'. Then pick a number around 50 times, keeping a count of how many of each you get, and how many times you get blue or green put together.

@Hudjefa I (and I think most people) have been assuming that you were a learner confused about probability, but looking at your post history I guess that's not the case. It would have been helpful and more productive if you had said where you were coming from to start with.

My reputation score is $985$, reversed it's $589$, Thank you for the downvote (if it was you sir/madam). I've edited my OP with a diagram and perhaps it'll go towards explaining my confusion.
